# Using pointers to adjust global objects in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, oop, object, pointers

Ok, so I am working with two sets of data that are extremely similar, and at the same time, these data sets are both global NSMutableArrays within the object.

```
data_set_one = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
data_set_two = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Two new NSMutableArrays are loaded, which need to be added to the old, existing data. These Arrays are also global.

```
xml_dataset_one = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
xml_dataset_two = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

To reduce code duplication (and because these data sets are *so* similar) I wrote a void method within the class to handle the data combination process for both Arrays:

```
-(void)constructData:(NSMutableArray *)data fromDownloadArray:(NSMutableArray *)down withMatchSelector:(NSString *)sel_str
```

Now, I have a decent understanding of object oriented programming, so I was thinking that if I were to invoke the method with the global Arrays in the data like so...

```
[self constructData:data_set_one fromDownloadArray:xml_dataset_one withMatchSelector:@"id"];
```

Then the global NSMutableArrays (data_set_one) would reflect the changes that happen to "array" within the method. Sadly, this is not the case, data_set_one doesn't reflect the changes (ex: new objects within the Array) outside of the method.

Here is a code snippet of the problem

```
// data_set_one is empty
// xml_dataset_one has a few objects

[constructData:(NSMutableArray *)data_set_one fromDownloadArray:(NSMutableArray *)xml_dataset_one withMatchSelector:(NSString *)@"id"];

// data_set_one should now be xml_dataset_one, but when echoed to screen, it appears to remain empty
```

And here is the gist of the code for the method, any help is appreciated.

```
-(void)constructData:(NSMutableArray *)data fromDownloadArray:(NSMutableArray *)down withMatchSelector:(NSString *)sel_str {
    if ([data count] == 0) {
        data = down;  // set data equal to downloaded data
    } else if ([down count] == 0) {
        // download yields no results, do nothing
    } else { 
        // combine the two arrays here 
    }
}
```

This project is not ARC enabled.

Thanks for the help guys!
Rob

Comment: I want data_set_one to retain the value it was given from the void method. It gets passed in, and is then altered via the pointer "data". Problem is, the changes made to data are not made to data_set_one. Edit, sorry I'm finding it difficult to explain my question :/

Comment: You need to retain its value. newValue=oldValue, where oldValue gets released results in nil to newValue. This is the issue here.

Comment: And one more thing..please use cocoa style of naming conventions.

Comment: Yeah I've tried retaining the value and hard copying it as well. Doesn't seem to work in this case...

And sorry, my bad :P you mean camel case?

Comment: yes camelCase and no_underscore, never give data to an array, because NSData is anothe className. Give full understadable name etc...

Comment: oooh, kk sorry. well thanks for the help, I wonder why this isn't working... hmm...

Comment: Sorry anoop, I ended up going to bed last night. I'm about to write an exam, I'll try using double pointers once I'm finished. Thank you for all the help I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your problem, you are trying to pass your object as call-by-reference and hoping to work as in C++/C. But Obj-C, although similar but has some different way. You have to dereference the object by using ** (double pointer) as mostly seen in NSError case, which is very rare.

Second ways is: wrap method as a block. Then put the variable in the same lexical scope as the block, and denote it by __block storage type.

Third way can be accessing your object directly by making it an ivar/property or even an singleton.

Comment: Thank you for the help, finally got around to it and the double pointer did the trick!